# What does "T::*" mean? - strange scope resolution operator

Tags: c++

I noticed these strange code from [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class). (Run it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1d182981e6316697)).

And I'm puzzled by `template <class T> char test(int T::*);`(at line 6). What's `int T::*` meaning? Is it representing a type correctly?

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <type_traits>

namespace my_impl {
    namespace detail {
        template <class T> char test(int T::*);
        struct two { char c[2]; };
        template <class T> two test(...);
    }

    template <class T>
    struct is_class : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(detail::test<T>(0))==1
                                                && !std::is_union<T>::value> {};
}
using my_impl::is_class;

struct A {};

class B {};

enum class C {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_class<A>() << '\n';
    std::cout << is_class<B>() << '\n';
    std::cout << is_class<C>() << '\n';
    std::cout << is_class<int>() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int T::*` is called a member pointer and it is a pointer to an `int`, but to an `int` that's a member of the class `T`. This is only a valid expression, if `T` is a class.